# How to Link image in html using folder path ? Or without Http or https

Tags: html, wordpress, image

How do i create url for images in wordpress without http or https.

for example how this website did it ? check below url

```
https://www.countries-ofthe-world.com/flags-normal/flag-of-Madagascar.png
https://www.countries-ofthe-world.com/flags-normal/flag-of-Albania.png
```

They use the images in html like this way. Means they link it without https or http.

```
<img src="flags-normal/flag-of-Albania.png" width="68" height="40" alt="Flag of Albania">
```

**My Thoughts:** I think the website is using folder "flags-normal" and inside it has all the images. So if this is true is it possible to add Src='flags-normal/image.png'> ? Or how to use it like the above example has done it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use both ways relative and absolute urls. You can also use only // slashes instead of http or https. It will represent both protocols.

Example:

```
<img src="//www.countries-ofthe-world.com/flags-normal/flag-of-Albania.png" width="68" height="40" alt="Flag of Albania">
```

Or

```
<img src="flags-normal/flag-of-Albania.png" width="68" height="40" alt="Flag of Albania">
```

Comment: Thanks bundles the way you teach me. I understand and it worked for me

Comment: your welcome :) Please never forget to accept answer :)